# Imagem ficando offline

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Conforme essa [Página](http://www.saichorao.com.br/campeonatos/eunachampions/) do site, algumas imagens estão ficando offline, vou no servidor, busco o endereço novamente e atualizo, porém 1 ou 2 dias depois fica desse jeito novamente, o interessante que são só algumas, as outras nunca aconteceram isso.

Obs. As imagens estão na parte de baixo da página, onde está escrito tabela.[image: Exemplo]

Quando digo que vou no servidor e copio novamente, eu pego o [link](http://files.saichorao.com.br/200001430-c1006c1fff/Galacticos.png?rnd=8846788831182086) e deleto o que está no final do link, deixando finalizando no .png... Isso interfere?

Onde cito o erro, na verdade é um iframe, o erro acontece nesse [iframe](http://files.saichorao.com.br/200001397-594005b32c/Eunachampions.html) que está na página.

Comment: A página do site não mostra essa tabela. Fica difícil de analisar o problema.

Comment: Deletar a querystring não interfere em nada. Sugiro que exclua mesmo visto que a imagem não sofrerá alteração. Colocar a querystring serve para que o navegador não use a imagem do cache. Sempre que a imagem é alterada você muda a querystring e o navegador usa a nova imagem em vez do cache mas no seu caso não é necessário.

Comment: Marco Antonio, acabei de clicar no link e mostrou a tabela sim, basta rolar um pouco a tela pra baixo, pouca coisa mesmo.

Comment: Conseguiu acessar?

Comment: Por que você está gerando pastas como 200001432-7ffdc8195c do endereço http://files.saichorao.com.br/200001432-7ffdc8195c/N%C3%81POLES-20EC.png?rnd=9775463935076285?

Comment: coloque as imagens dentro de uma pasta comum e chame elas de acordo com o time.